# Reversing key value pairs in a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a data structure as follows:

```
Map<String,ArrayList<String>> graph = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
```

This is essentially a hash map which puts string values as keys and stores array list of strings in the value for the keys. 
Now I am trying to reverse the key value pattern to make value the key and key the value. The way I am doing it is as follows:

```
private Map<String,ArrayList<String>> reverseAdjList(Map<String,ArrayList<String>> adjList){
    Map<String,ArrayList<String>> tGraph = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : adjList.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(key);
        ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();    
        for(String v:value){
            if(tGraph.containsKey(v)){
                values.addAll(tGraph.get(v));
            }
            tGraph.put(v, values);
        }
    }
    return tGraph;
}
```

So this works for me in reversing the hash map keys values pattern for small data set however when I try it on a larger dataset I run into

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227)
at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:579)
at GraphProcessor.reverseAdjList(GraphProcessor.java:67)
at GraphProcessor.SCC(GraphProcessor.java:135)
at GraphProcessor.<init>(GraphProcessor.java:50)
at GraphProcessor.main(GraphProcessor.java:250)
```

I know this is a very naïve and wrong approach to do it, what is a better and correct way to do it?

Comment: How large is your dataset? Maybe you just need to increase your jvm heap size with `-Xmx`

Comment: Your code is wrong. `values` is only instantiated once per key and it grows exponentially for each value. Try moving `ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();` to the inner `for` loop. Better yet, add `key` to the previously mapped list instead of copying every time.

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much that fixed it. Also thanks for the suggestion of using a key.

Comment: Sorry I found your bug by trying your code and post it as an answer but shmosel has commented it, there's also some refactor thinkings in the answer so I decide to keep it, hope it could be helpful.

Comment: Not a problem, I really appreciate you trying to help me @shizhz. Thank you so much also I found your answer really helpful and it was very well-explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bug in your code:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : adjList.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>(); // Wrong place for this variable.
    values.add(key);
    ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();    
    for(String v:value){
        if(tGraph.containsKey(v)){
            values.addAll(tGraph.get(v));
        }
        tGraph.put(v, values);
    }
}
```

The local variable `values` should be in the nested `for` loop, otherwise `values` are accumulated for all later new key `v` and will cost a lot of memory if your dataset is large, it should be:

```
private Map<String, ArrayList<String>> reverseAdjList(Map<String, List<String>> adjList) {
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> tGraph = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : adjList.entrySet())  {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<String> value = entry.getValue();
        for (String v : value) {
            ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
            values.add(key);
            if (tGraph.containsKey(v)) {
                values.addAll(tGraph.get(v));
            }
            tGraph.put(v, values);
        }
    }
    return tGraph;
}
```

But actually you don't need to create a new List instance for each inner `for` step, try the following code with JDK 1.8:

```
private  Map<String, List<String>> reverseMap(Map<String, List<String>> adjList) {
    Map<String, List<String>> tGraph = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : adjList.entrySet()) {
        for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
            tGraph.computeIfAbsent(value, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add(entry.getKey()); // Updated according comment from @shmosel
        }
    }
    return tGraph;
}
```

If you're using older version of jdk, you can try:

```
    private Map<String, List<String>> reverseMap(Map<String, List<String>> adjList) {
    Map<String, List<String>> tGraph = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : adjList.entrySet()) {
        for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
            List<String> newValues = tGraph.get(value);
            if (newValues == null) {
                newValues = new ArrayList<>();
                tGraph.put(value, newValues);
            }
            newValues.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return tGraph;
}
```

Hope this could be helpful :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! this is extremely helpful.

Comment: @smriti Very glad to help :-)

Comment: A better solution in Java 8: `tGraph.computeIfAbsent(value, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add(entry.getKey());`

Comment: @shmosel, this is really cool, thank you very much. I've updated the answer  :)